# ASCII characters not getting printed out

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I want to read cards from an input file and print out their values.

However when I try to print out characters it prints out `'0'`.

If I print  out the character `'A'`, then normally the int value `65` is supposed to be printed out since I stored the character `'A'` as an Int.

Could anyone help me out?

Thank you in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define max 100
#define MAX_LENGTH 14

int main(){
  char *lines = malloc(max*sizeof(char));

    char **colour = malloc(max*sizeof(char));
    int *value =malloc(max*sizeof(int));
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("config2.txt", "r");
    if(fp == NULL){
        printf("Cannot open filelist.txt\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int i= 0;
    while (i < max && fgets(lines, MAX_LENGTH, fp) != NULL) { 
        colour[i] = malloc(MAX_LENGTH); 
        sscanf(lines, "%s %d", colour[i], &value[i]);
        printf("%s\n", colour[i]);
        printf("%d\n", value[i]);

        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

input:

```
RED A
RED 2
RED 3
RED 4
RED 5
RED 6
RED 7
RED 8
RED 9
RED 10
RED J
RED Q
RED K
```

Comment: I'd start by checking the return value of `sscanf`. If you're not reading the data correctly it's not going to print correctly.

Comment: @Retired NinjaThe return value of sscanf can either be null,0 or 1 I think in my case it's 0. I don't understand how I didn't read the data correctly.

Comment: @momonosu You ask it to read an int with %d, but supplied letters which are not numbers, i.e. 'A'.  So, it failed to read it correctly.

Comment: As @Serge said, letters can't be read with `%d`, but you have other problems too. `char **colour = malloc(max*sizeof(char));` needs to be `char **colour = malloc(max*sizeof(char*));` since you are allocating pointers to characters, not characters. if `sscanf` isn't returning 2 then you're not reading the data correctly.

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("Cannot open filelist.txt\n");
        return 1;`  1) error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  2) when the error indication is from a C library function, should also output the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  An excellent way to do this is: `perror( "foen failed" );  exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your primary problem handling either `'A'` or an integer as the value, stems from the misunderstanding that `A` can be parsed with `sscanf` using the `"%d"` *format specifier*, it can't. Why? When you attempt to parse `'A'` with `"%d"` a *matching failure* occurs, no further characters are extracted from the input buffer, and the **return** for `sscanf` will be the number of successful conversions that took place prior to the failure.

When you have data of differing types, e.g.

```
RED A
RED 2
```

In order to parse the values for `A` or `2`, it will require two different `sscanf` expressions, which you can easily distinguish simply by *checking the* **return** for `sscanf`. You do this in a conditional and if parsing with `"%s %d"` fails, you attempt the parse with `"%s %c"` and validate whether that succeeded.

For instance, say instead of allocating with `malloc` (you are not reallocating anyway), you simply declare an array of struct to hold the `color` and `value` read from each line, e.g.

```
...
#define MAXCOLR   14
#define MAXLINE  100
#define MAXCHR  1024    /* don't skimp on read buffer size */

typedef struct {        /* simple struct to associate each color/value */
    char color[MAXCOLR];
    int value;
} colorval_t;

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    size_t ndx = 0;     /* index */
    char buf[MAXCHR];   /* read buffer */
    colorval_t arr[MAXLINE] = {{ .color = "" }};    /* array of struct */
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;
    ...
    while (ndx < MAXLINE && fgets (buf, MAXCHR, fp)) {
        char c;     /* temp char to use for parsing 2nd case */
        if (sscanf (buf, "%13s %d", arr[ndx].color, &arr[ndx].value) == 2)
            ndx++;
        else if (sscanf (buf, "%13s %c", arr[ndx].color, &c) == 2) {
            arr[ndx].value = c;
            ndx++;
        }
    }
```

The `while` loop above being the operative code for handling the parse of information read from each line into `buf`. The first `sscanf` call attempts the parse into a string and integer value. If the return is not `2`, then a second call to `sscanf` is made to attempt to parse the contents into a string and a character. If that succeeds, the character value (e.g. the ASCII value for the character) is assigned to `value`, which from your question appears to be what you intended.

Adding a few validations and then outputting the `color` and `value` for each struct contained in `arr`, you could do something like the following. (**note:** the program takes the filename to read as the first argument or reads from `stdin` by default if no argument is given. Don't hardcode filenames. Either pass the filename as an argument or prompt for its entry)

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXCOLR   14
#define MAXLINE  100
#define MAXCHR  1024    /* don't skimp on read buffer size */

typedef struct {
    char color[MAXCOLR];
    int value;
} colorval_t;

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    size_t ndx = 0;
    char buf[MAXCHR];
    colorval_t arr[MAXLINE] = {{ .color = "" }};
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }

    while (ndx < MAXLINE && fgets (buf, MAXCHR, fp)) {
        char c;
        if (sscanf (buf, "%13s %d", arr[ndx].color, &arr[ndx].value) == 2)
            ndx++;
        else if (sscanf (buf, "%13s %c", arr[ndx].color, &c) == 2) {
            arr[ndx].value = c;
            ndx++;
        }
    }
    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);   /* close file if not stdin */

    for (size_t i = 0; i < ndx; i++)
        printf ("arr[%2zu] : %-14s %d\n", i, arr[i].color, arr[i].value);

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** the use of the *field-width* modifier `13` to protect the character array bounds for `color`)

**Example Use/Output**

Using your data as input would result in the following:

```
$ ./bin/rdcolorval <dat/colorval.txt
arr[ 0] : RED            65
arr[ 1] : RED            2
arr[ 2] : RED            3
arr[ 3] : RED            4
arr[ 4] : RED            5
arr[ 5] : RED            6
arr[ 6] : RED            7
arr[ 7] : RED            8
arr[ 8] : RED            9
arr[ 9] : RED            10
arr[10] : RED            74
arr[11] : RED            81
arr[12] : RED            75
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.  I have trouble understanding this `colorval_t arr[MAXLINE] = {{ .color = "" }};`  does

Comment: If you look at the `typedef` for the `stuct` it is named `colorval_t`. So `colorval_t arr[MAXLINE]` simply declares an array of struct (named `arr`) with `MAXLINE` elements. The *named initializer* used `{{ .color = "" }};` simply initializes the `color` member for every element in the array to the empty-string (all zeros) and by default then all `value` members are initialized to zero as well. (so it just declares an array of struct and initializes all elements to zero) Using a struct to coordinate the `color` and `value` is cleaner than using multiple arrays.

Comment: I get it now. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. does not keep the contents of every line, rather  only of the current line.  You might want to change that
2. properly checks for errors
3. does not use dynamic memory allocation. You might want to change that
4. cleanly compiles
5. Does not include header files those contents are not used
6. Properly cleans up (closes files) when exiting either normally or when a call to `sscanf()` fails.
7. uses a valid signature for `main()`
8. uses the convention of defined values being in all capitals
9. properly uses MAX CHARACTERS modifier on the input format specifier `%s` so as to avoid any possibility of a buffer overflow and the resulting undefined behavior
10. documents why each header file is being included
11. does NOT correct the mismatch between the incoming data and the call to `sscanf()` Strongly suggest you read about `atoi()` and `strtol()` and modify the call to `sscanf()` to expect two char sequences and save them accordingly.

And now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>   // printf(), fprintf(), sscanf()
#include <stdlib.h>  // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE


//#define MAX_LINES 100
#define MAX_LENGTH 14


int main( void )
{
    char lines[ MAX_LENGTH +1];
    char colour[ MAX_LENGTH ];

    int  value;

    FILE *fp = fopen( "config2.txt", "r" );
    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        perror( "fopen to read config2.txt failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }


    while ( fgets( lines, MAX_LENGTH, fp ) ) 
    {   
        if( sscanf(lines, "%100s %d", colour, &value) != 2 )
        {
            fprintf( stderr,  "sscanf to extract two fields from input line failed\n" );
            fclose( fp );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        printf( "colour: %s\n", colour );
        printf( "value:  %d\n", value );
    }
    fclose( fp );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A very detailed answer (nice) but it does not solve OPs question. Executing the program just gives: "sscanf to extract two fields from input line failed". Some nitpick comments: a) `lines` doesn't need `MAX_LENGTH +1` b) Even if it is a good habit to avoid scan with `%s` this case doesn't need `%100s` as `colour` has the same size as `lines`.

Comment: @4386427,  I did mention that the the OP would need to modify the posted answer to read two strings, and that the OP would need to be handling the conversion of the second string (if it is numeric)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is pretty close to something that works. The main problem is that you can **not** scan a line like "RED A" using the format specifier "%s %d" as A is not an integer. Instead you can scan it using a char.

Further you have a problem with the `malloc` of `colour`. You need to do `sizeof(char*)` as you want an array of char pointers.

So try something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define max 100
#define MAX_LENGTH 14

int main(){
  char *filename = "config2.txt";
  char *lines = malloc(max*sizeof(char));
  char **colour = malloc(max*sizeof(char*));  // Use sizeof(char*)
  char *value =malloc(max*sizeof(char));      // Use char instead of int
  FILE *fp;

  fp = fopen(filename, "r");
  if(fp == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open %s : ", filename);
    perror("");
    exit(1);
  }

  int i= 0;
  while (i < max && fgets(lines, MAX_LENGTH, fp) != NULL) {
    colour[i] = malloc(MAX_LENGTH);
    if (sscanf(lines, "%s %c", colour[i], &value[i]) != 2)  // Use %c instead of %d and check return value
    {
      printf("Unexpected input file data\n");
      exit(1);
    }
    printf("%s ", colour[i]);
    printf("%c (%d)\n", value[i], value[i]);       // Print value as both char and int

    i++;
  }

  // Clean up
  fclose (fp);
  for (int j = 0; j<i; ++j) free(colour[j]);
  free(colour);
  free(value);

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
RED A (65)
RED 2 (50)
RED 3 (51)
RED 4 (52)
RED 5 (53)
RED 6 (54)
RED 7 (55)
RED 8 (56)
RED 9 (57)
RED 1 (49)
RED J (74)
RED Q (81)
RED K (75)
```

Also notice that you should always check the return value of `malloc`. Example:

```
SomeType *someVar = malloc(sizeof(SomeType));  // or better malloc(sizeof *momeVar);
if (someVar == NULL)
{
    // Out of memory - add error handling (e.g. terminate program)
}
```